# Where can I find a list of all methods of javascript objects?

Tags: javascript

I just learned that `alert()` is a method of the `window` object.  I also just learned that `getElementById()` is a method of the `document` object.

Is there a place where I can find documentation as to what methods belong to certain objects?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [Mozilla Developer Network documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). It's quite good.

For example, you can find documentation on the both [`window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window) and the [`document.getElementById()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).

For a quick sandbox to try stuff out, you could try [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or even just the JS console in Google Chrome (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>).

Comment: Direct link into MDN JS Method List: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Methods_Index

Answer (score 2):

for any object, like window for example, you can do something like:

```
for(var prop in window){
   console.log(prop);
   console.debug(window[prop]);
}
```

log will tell you the name of the property and debug will show you the details

Answer (score 1):

Try this place
http://krook.org/jsdom/

Also:
I'd suggest downloading Firebug addon for firefox. Use the DOM tab and you'll be able to browse which methods live where in the browser.